# How diachronically stable are color terms?

Tags: historical-linguistics, colour-terms

I have two questions concerning words for colors, one specific and one general.

First, Beekes in *Comparative Indo-European Linguistics: An Introduction* (p. 181) reconstructs a PIE suffix *–no-* that forms adjectives.  An example is * *krs-nó-* ‘black’:  Skt. *kṛṣṇá-,* OCS *črъnъ* *(<*čъrsn-)* (so Russian *черный*).  Several color terms in Latvian, such as *sarkans* ‘red’ and *dzeltens* ‘yellow’ look like they might also fall into this category.  Can anyone confirm this?

Now the more general question.  How diachronically stable are color terms?

On the one hand, there is an argument for stability.  We can broadly distinguish core or basic vocabulary from cultural vocabulary.  Introductory historical linguistics textbooks say that core vocabulary tends to be conserved because it is less susceptible to borrowing.*  Most languages will include a certain number of color words in their core vocabulary.  Simply because they are ‘basic’, we can assume that these color words are fairly conservative.  The fact that children learn color words very early also suggests that transmission of these words across generations of speakers is likely to be relatively stable.

On the other hand, I can think of several paths by which color words might be replaced over time.  Colors may be associated with certain nouns (like blue with the sky), which might come to be used in place of the color (like ‘salmon’ as a color).  Or some factor of material culture, e.g. how dyes are produced, might influence the color word used.  Examples here might include Chinese characters for colors with the grass, bamboo or silk radicals (藍, 紅), which seem to reflect a physical source like the indigo plant.**

I am aware of Berlin and Kay’s study of color systems, and that seems to be mainly synchronic.  To what extent can we reconstruct color terms for PIE?

---

*cf.  Terry Crowley, *An Introduction to Historical Linguistics* (2nd ed. 1992), p. 153: “Languages are more likely to copy words from other languages in the area of *cultural vocabulary*, rather than *core vocabulary*.  Core vocabulary is basically vocabulary that we can expect to find in all human languages.”  Five basic color words (red, green, yellow, black and white) were included on Swadesh’s 100-word list.

**There is an additional consideration:  color words may have other meanings besides that of color, as in Chinese 青  *qīng*, which can mean ‘young’ in addition to green or blue.  In extreme cases like Hanunoo, these additional semantic dimensions can accrue and throw into question the existence of a color system as such.  See the discussion of universalist vs. relativist approaches to color terminology in Chapter 7 of William Foley’s *Anthropological Linguistics:  An Introduction* (1997).

Comment: Russian word for 'red', красный, derives from the word that means 'beautiful', this word for 'red' is found only in Russian. The Russian word for 'brown', коричневый, derives from 'кора', 'bark of trees'. Words for 'yellow' and 'green' are obviously related in all the Slavic languages.

Comment: Apparently it is very difficult to make sense of colour terms in Latin texts, as if they must've shifted but not in straightforward ways. Japan aquired their word for "green" (みどり) so recently that green traffic lights are still referred to as "blue" (あおい).

Comment: Actually this question was prompted by a recent Chinese SE discussion, interesting but inconclusive, about the Chinese words for green and blue.  It’s here:  http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6832/what-is-the-difference-between-%e7%bb%bf-and-%e9%9d%92

Comment: @hippietrail, strictly speaking, Japanese has had みどり for a very long time, but the use of it for the color is more recent. Also, when traffic lights were first introduced in Japan, they were legally referred to as 緑色信号, but people seemed to prefer 青信号, so that name took over. Your comment might lead people to believe that the color みどり is newer than traffic lights, which is not the case.

Comment: For I-E, you probly want to read Buck's treatment of color terms (in Chapter 15 "Sense Perception," sections 15.51 `SEE` through 15.69 `YELLOW`, pp 1040-59) in his _[Dictionary of Selected Synonyms in the Principal Indo-European Languages](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1013/482)_.

Comment: I would assume that color terms are very unstable because of the nature of the color domain, which has no clear internal boundaries. It should be very easy for a term to shift gradually from meaning e.g. "blue" to "turquoise" to "green" to "yellow".

Comment: @dainichi: Yes I should have said "sense" rather than word, but it's probably enough for people to still go and look up the topic to get a real understanding (-: But thanks for the heads up - always expect the unexpected in every field of linguistics (=

Comment: @TKR: It's not really accurate to say "no clear internal boundaries" as the human eye is based on three kinds of wavelength perceptors, so red, green, and blue have some kind of natural boundaries, for what that's worth.

Comment: @hippietrail That's true, but given that that neurological fact doesn't stop very many languages from conflating "blue" and "green", I don't know to what extent it might constrain semantic change in the color domain, if at all.

Comment: @TKR: Agreed, however I thought if it's worth noting the one point it's worth noting both. It's all pretty interesting in a "linguistics defies intuition" kinda way (-:

Comment: *primary color words can be considered part of the core vocabulary of any language* - this isn't necessarily true. Some languages have been argued to lack any words corresponding to English-type pure color terms. (For an example see H. Conklin 1955, "Hanunóo color categories", Southwest Journal of Anthropology 11:339-44.)

Comment: For a really interesting read, Guy Deutscher's "through the language glass" gives a really interesting and, at least seemingly, quite thorough look at the history of this topic.

Comment: not exactly what you asked for but still relevant - Kay 1975 http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/Var&Change.pdf

Comment: @TKR:  I've edited the question in response to your comments.

Comment: On the PIE question, if you can get hold of Mallory and Adams' Oxford Intro to PIE and the PIE World, they give reconstructed vocab in most semantic domains, and I believe there are a few pages on IE color terms.

Answer (score 6):

At least for Romance and Germanic languages, the colour terms seem to be less stable than other parts of the core vocabulary. Examples:

- Latin *flavius* and english *blue* are cognates, but *flavius* means yellow. Speculation: This particular semantic shift may be explained by the chemical details of dying blue with woad or indigo
- Modern Romance languages have replaced the original Latin words for blue with newer borrowings (French *bleu*, Italian *azzurro*)
- Likewise, the old Latin term *albus* "white" was replaced by loans in most modern Romance languages (*bianco* in Italian, *blanc/blanche* in French)
- Actually, the English word *black* is cognate to *blanche/blanc*. German uses *schwarz* "black"
- (EDIT) The German cognate of *black* is not a colour term at all, it is *blank* "pure, sheer"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of empirical diachronic data off the top of my head, but some people have investigated the evolution of color lexicons with simulations. See these papers:

Loreto, Vittorio; Mukherjee, Animesh; Tria, Francesca
On the origin of the hierarchy of color names (Article)
PROCEEDINGS OF THE NATIONAL ACADEMY OF SCIENCES OF THE UNITED STATES OF AMERICA (PNAS), 2012.

Baronchelli, Andrea; Gong, Tao; Puglisi, Andrea; Loreto, Vittorio
Modeling the emergence of universality in color naming patterns (Article)
PROCEEDINGS OF THE NATIONAL ACADEMY OF SCIENCES OF THE UNITED STATES OF AMERICA (PNAS), 107 pp. 2403–2407, 2010.

EDIT: Commenter below is right that I should say a little something about these papers. I'm just pulling key points from their abstracts:

Loreto et al:

> We found that the time needed for a [simulated] population to reach consensus on a color name depends on the region of the visible color spectrum. If color spectrum regions are ranked according to this criterion, a hierarchy with [red, (magenta)-red], [violet], [green/yellow], [blue], [orange], and [cyan], appearing in this order, is recovered, featuring an excellent quantitative agreement with the empirical observations of the [World Color Survey].

Baronchelli et al:

> We find that a simple perceptual constraint shared by all humans, namely the human Just Noticeable Difference (JND), is sufficient to trigger the emergence of universal patterns that unconstrained cultural interaction fails to produce. We test the results of our experiment against real data by performing the same statistical analysis proposed to quantify the universal tendencies shown in the WCS [Kay P & Regier T. (2003) Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA 100: 9085-9089], and obtain an excellent quantitative agreement.

Comment: Please consider adding some key points from the linked papers into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, medium. Taking for instance, Indo-European family, there are a lot of color words that changed meaning and also a lot of invented words, but some words are surprisingly stable.

For instance,

- English, Russian, Greek, Italian, all have a word for at least a dye of red color inherited from the same PIE word ***e̯roudhros*** meaning "red".
- English, Russian, Italian(possibly from Germanic), Greek, Persian all have the word for yellow or green inherited from the same PIE word, ***ĝhelo̯u̯os*** meaning "yellow-green".
- English, Russian (borrowed from Indo-Iranian), Italian (borrowed from Germanic), Greek, Persian all have the word for brown originated from PIE ***bhrunos*** "brown"

But the words for blue or grey are not shared at all. This may indicate that the proto-language simply had no word for these colors.

Comment: Actually, *gholtos only seems to be the ancestor of the Balto-Slavic word for "gold." Other language groups used the same root, but with different suffixes, to make their words meaning "yellow." [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/ǵʰelh₃-) lists the PIE root as *ǵʰelh₃, while the OED entry on English"yellow" says it is from PIE *ghelwo- with the root ghol- : ghel- : ghl-.

Comment: @sumelic the precise form of this word in PIE is unclear.

Comment: Aren't Italian bruno "brown" and French brun "brown" borrowings from Germanic languages? And what are the Russian and Greek terms you are referring to (I found Russian koríčnevy and Greek καστανό as words for "brown")?

Comment: And for the terms of Green/Yellow: How is Italian *giallo* "yellow" connected to PIE *ĝhelo̯u̯os? The natural reflex of this root is Latin *helvus*, not *galbinus* which developped into *giallo*.

Comment: @jknappen Russian бурый means brown http://www.lingvo-online.ru/ru/Translate/en-ru/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9 . Italian giallo is from Latin galbinus, extended from galbus. Bruno is indeed a borrowing from Germanic.

Comment: Latin galbus is also a borrowing from Germanic, isn't it?

Comment: @sumelic no if to trust dictionaries

Comment: Then where is it from? The initial "g" is not the expected reflex of PIE *gh for an inherited word.

Comment: @sumelic well, possibly, indeed, Germanic